# how to define the model with static key as well as dynamic key in typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, nestjs

```
export class person {
    [key: string]: CustomeObject;
    requestType: string;
    status: number;
}
```

need to create the model with a static key as well as the dynamic key in typescript.
but getting the following error
Property 'status' of type 'number' is not assignable to string index type 'OperationObject'

```
export class CustomeObject {
    Type: string;
    Percent: number;
    metadata: object;
    retrySequence: number;
    status: number;
}
```

how can I fix this here?